# VueJS + Axios: Fetched data are modified in Console Tab vs Network Tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I make request with Axios from VueJS app and log the response data in console. I don't understand how but data are modified by my VueJS app and are different from original fetched data in Network Tab in ChromeDevTool.

My request:

```
axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: some-url,
    headers: some-headers,
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.data.params)
    this.parameters = response.data.data.params // assign data for next modifications
})
.then(() => {
    for (let parameter of this.parameters){
        parameter.invalid = false
    }
})
```

As you can see, I process (parameter.invalid = false) later than console.log, but data in Console Tab are modified compare to original data in Network Tab.

[Screenshot of original data (there is NOT "invalid" attribute)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQQzj.png)

[Screenshot of console data (modified data with "invalid" attribute)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwPp6.png)

Has anyone experienced the same behavior?

Thank you

ventil

Comment: Objects logged to the console are live. The properties are only captured when you expand the object by clicking on it within the console.

Comment: Put your mouse over that i icon it - thats why